# The type or namespace name 'SQLite' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-4.0, system.data.sqlite

I am using .net framework 4.0, I don't understand how to fix this issue:

I keep receiving this message: The type or namespace name 'SQLite' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' and the function SQLiteConnetion is not recognized

Comment: No you don't need any thing else. Just make sure you installed System.Data.SQlite not Microsoft.Data.SQLite. Second one is for dot net core.

Comment: I did, but the problem isn't solved, should I try to unistall it and install it again so that it might solve the problem ?

Comment: of course, it might help.

Comment: I have discovered that I need to install the System.Data.SQLite again, I did install it for the previsou project but now when I checked it showed not installed, that means I have to reinstall it for every project, it doesn't install once for all future projects, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when installing any package kindly check that the minimum target framework is reached this may help you to sort it out, and in all cases, you can achieve the desired tasks by following this scenario:

1. Install-Package Microsoft.Data.Sqlite -Version 5.0.7
2. set project target framework to 4.6.2
3. using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
4. code snippet will be something like the following

   ```
       string connectionStr = "//////";
       using (var con = new SqliteConnection(connectionStr))
       {
           con.Open();
           var cmd = new SqliteCommand("SELECT SQLITE_VERSION()", con);
           string version = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
           Console.WriteLine($"SQLite version: {version}");
       }
   ```

Comment: I found out that the package has not been installed for this new project even though I installed the previous time when I was working on another project, apparently I need to reinstall it each time I start a new project where I would use sqlite, right ?

Comment: Microsoft.Data.Sqlite is for dot net core. System.Data.Sqlite is for dot net framework.

Comment: you are right packages need to be installed for each project to be able to use package classes in this project, and nice to hear that the problem has been fixed.